# haskell error function

Tags: haskell

I have one function `first` with type: `Int -> [a] -> (Error ([a],[a]))` and a second function `second` with type: `[a] ->  [a] -> [a]`

I am trying to make a third function now that uses the above functions.
the type I have for this function is:  `[Int] -> [a] -> Error [a]`

I have been given these types to work around so cant change them.

This is what I tried:

```
last :: [Int] -> [a] -> Error [a]
last (x:xs) list = second (first x list)
```

Can you pass outputs from functions that use the error function in to others?

Comment: Function names must be lower case. Have you tried implementing this?

Comment: @Joel you can have functions with upper case names. They're also known as *data constructors* (ok, maybe function-like values?). E.g. `Just :: a -> Maybe a`.

Comment: I understand that data constructors are upper case, but `F` and `Q` are not data constructors.

Comment: i have changed the function names, that was just for the example, fixed.

Comment: What is `Error` here? The answer from Martinho seems to imply that it is a monad, is it so?

Comment: @Ed'ka: Ooops... I assumed it was the Error monad from Control.Monad.Error. But only now did I realise that the Error exported by that is a class, not a type constructor. So, it is probably a custom data type. I edited my answer to make my assumption of its monadic nature explicit. @Lunar If it isn't a monad, please make it clear. In that case, knowing the data type definition is important because you'll need pattern matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Error` is  an [error monad](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/5103.html), you can use the monadic bind operator (`>>=`) and the `uncurry` function:

```
z (x:xs) list = F x list >>= return . uncurry Q
```

`uncurry` transforms Q from a function with two arguments (aka a curried function) into a function on pairs. This means that `uncurry Q :: ([a], [a]) -> [a]`

The bind operator takes a value out of a monad and passes it into a monadic function. Here we're extracting the value of the Error monad returned by `F` and passing it to `Q`, now turned into a monadic function that works on a pair of lists, thanks to `return` and `uncurry`.

Comment: You can also use the functor instance instead: `z (x:_) list = uncurry Q <$> F x list`

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks! I knew there was a way to write `fmap (uncurry Q) (F x list)` that looked elegant without parenthesis. I just couldn't remember what the operator was. I guess my Haskell is getting rusty :(

Comment: @Marthino Fernandes: The problem is, that the Prelude doesn't exports `<$>` by default.