# applying my functions?

Tags: haskell

I made these two haskell functions,

```
cut :: Int -> [a] -> (Error ([a],[a]))
cut _ [] = Ok([],[])
cut n xs | n>0 && n < length xs = Ok(take n xs, drop n xs) 
           | n > length xs = error("Fail")

mix ::  [a] ->  [a] -> [a]
mix xs [] = xs
mix [] ys = ys
mix (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:mix xs ys
```

An now wish to make anouther function in which i can use both of these,

this is what i have;

```
doboth :: [Int] -> [a] -> Error [a]
doboth (x:xs) list = mix((cut x list)) then send xs back to doboth recursivly for the next x elemet of the list.
```

The idea of this function is to cut a list and then mix the two lists, it gets the cut points from the do both list of ints...

ANy ideas?

Comment: What is `interleave`? Is it `mix`?

Comment: The Ok alternative is the same as Ok (splitAt n xs).

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421704/haskell-error-function ?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework problem, so my answer is more thought provoking than a direct answer. If you need more help thinking about a particular aspect, let us know.

Comment: thanks for your comments, yes it is, you have game something to think about, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cut returns not a list, you need to pattern match a bit:

```
case cut x list of
    Ok (as, bs) -> mix ... ... -- and so forth
```

Comment: that works nicely for one elsement , how could i get it to work recursivly?

Comment: It depends how you want to combine the results. If you want a list, then it would look like (mix .... : doboth xs list)

Comment: The more general answer is: if something works nicely for one element, leave it at that and use the function together with map/fold and the like.

Comment: I have this;
doboth (x:xs) list = case cut x list of
  Ok (as, bs) -> map doboth xs (mix as bs)

I know how map works, but im unsure of how to apply it ot these functions, as i need to pull in the tail of the list xs. so i can repeat doboth with xs and the result from (mix as bs), im fairly new too all this

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't doboth return Error [[a]]?

Maybe you should use a standard type like Maybe or Either instead Error.

If I understand what you want correctly, then doboth would be something like

```
doboth xs list = mapM (\ x -> mix (cut x list)) xs
```

Assuming you've made Error into a monad (which Maybe and Either already are).

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions you have to ask yourself:

- Does `cut` have to return an `Error` value? Or can you come up with a reasonable definition that works for all inputs. For example, `tail` doesn't work for all inputs, whereas `take` does. Investigate `take` and see how it handles exceptional inputs. This might lead you to a better definition of `cut`. The reason this is important is that functions that return uniform results for all values are generally much easier to work with.
- What do you expect `doboth` to do if the result of the `cut` is an error?
- Does `doboth` operate on elements of a list independently? Or are the result dependent on earlier computations? The first is `map` like, the second `fold` like. You want to perform a `cut` and `mix` for each value in the `[Int]` input, but should the input to `cut` be the original list, or the list from the previous step?
- Given that you have computed one step of `doboth`, what should the next step of `doboth` look like? Try writing out the code that would do two, or even three, steps of `doboth` at once.
- What is the value of `doboth` if the `[Int]` argument is empty?